# Add string to column based on length of entry

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a df:

```
1.colour     code
2.red        1234
3.blue       234
4.yellow     4567
5.green      456
```

with column and need too add a string based on length of the entry. i have tried:

```
 i = 0
 mylist = df['code']
 mystring3 = ('D')   
 mystring4 = ('B')

 for i in range(len(mylist)):
     if len(mylist[i]) == 3:
        mylist[i] = mystring3 +  mylist[i]
     else:
        mylist[i] = mystring4 +  mylist[i]
    i+=1
```

this takes long and i lose position of my colour column. How do i keep position in place even the duplicates 
Many thanks J

Comment: Can you add more explanation? What kind of string?

Comment: Apologies, i pressed enter by mistake and only part of question was asked.

Comment: Hi Jienkles! Thanks for adding more info but I highly doubt that this code is working. As I can see unclosed parentheses.

Comment: Can you add a sample dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to do the expected.

I added `str()` around the `x` as I first had datatype `int` for the `code` column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'colour':['red','blue','yellow','green'],'code':['1234','234','4567','456']})

df['code'] = df['code'].apply(lambda x: 'D' + str(x) if len(str(x)) == 3 else 'B' + str(x))

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   colour   code
0     red  B1234
1    blue   D234
2  yellow  B4567
3   green   D456
```

Like this you would be also able to add a new column and still keep the old:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'colour':['red','blue','yellow','green'],'code':['1234','234','4567','456']})

df['code_new'] = df['code'].apply(lambda x: 'D' + str(x) if len(str(x)) == 3 else 'B' + str(x))

print(df)
```

New Result:

```
   colour  code code_new
0     red  1234    B1234
1    blue   234     D234
2  yellow  4567    B4567
3   green   456     D456
```